# How to select a text from the autocomplete textbox using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I need to enter some text in a autocomplete textbox.
Then I will select a option from that autocomplete option and need to click it.

I have tried with the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String textToSelect = "headlines today";

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    WebElement autoOptions= driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib"));
    autoOptions.sendKeys("he");

    List<WebElement> optionsToSelect = driver.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

    for(WebElement option : optionsToSelect){
        System.out.println(option);
        if(option.getText().equals(textToSelect)) {
            System.out.println("Trying to select: "+textToSelect);
            option.click();
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: @VikasNehaOjha In my code the for loop iteration is not running

Comment: @HelpingHands It is not showing any error! But, the program is keep on running. In optionsToSelect it is getting the list of values. I'm trying to iterate it in *for loop* and comparing the values.

Comment: Do a sleep or an explicit wait before the `List<WebElement> optionsToSelect`. Also try to print the list before the `for` loop so you can see the number of elements in the list.

Comment: Yeah it is working. I have used the xpath instead of tag name. Now it is working. Also I have added the explicit wait too. Thanks Vikas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
String textToSelect = "headlines today";

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
Thread.sleep(2000);
WebElement autoOptions= driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib"));
autoOptions.sendKeys("he");

List<WebElement> optionsToSelect = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='sbqs_c']"));

for(WebElement option : optionsToSelect){
    System.out.println(option);
    if(option.getText().equals(textToSelect)) {
        System.out.println("Trying to select: "+textToSelect);
        option.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this i have used google home page auto suggest as an example

```
public class AutoSelection {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("mahatama gandhi");
        List<WebElement> autoSuggest = driver.findElements(By
            .xpath("//div[@class='sbqs_c']"));
        // verify the size of the list
        System.out
            .println("Size of the AutoSuggets is = " + autoSuggest.size());
        // print the auto suggest
        for (WebElement a : autoSuggest)
            System.out.println("Values are = " + a.getText());
        // suppose now you want to click on 3rd auto suggest then simply do like
        // this
        autoSuggest.get(2).click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply rajnish. But in my case I need to compare the exact string/text in that suggestion. Instead of giving as index values inside get().

Comment: But any how I found the error that I used the tag name instead of using xpath. Now it works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
driverName.findElement(By.xpath("XPATH Location")).sendKeys("KeyNameYouWantToSearch" , Keys.TAB);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use java 8 stream API to filter and collect Web elements in an Array. Clicking will be easier using index.

// Collect 5 autocomplete entries lists

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#ui-id-1 
li:nth-child(n)")).stream()
            .limit(5)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

// This will click the first element from an autocompleted list

```
list.get(0).click();
```